# ASCIIMath and TiddlyWiki

Tags: javascript, tiddlywiki

I use [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) for work-notes. I already have pretty large wiki, but now I want to add math-support. As far as I understand what is written [here](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimathdownload/), all I would have to do to use ASCIIMathML in my wiki would be including the script ASCIIMathML.js. Doesn't work (no effect at all). Then I found this [plugin](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~psoares/asciimathml.html#ASCIIMathMLPlugin%20GettingStarted) for TiddlyWiki, but when I import it to my wiki, it gives me an error in one of the regexp strings. When I download that wiki directly, ASCIIMath does not work anymore, even though I have the script in the same directory.

Does anyone have a solution available, how I can add ASCIIMath to my existing TiddlyWiki?

**Edit:** I know this not strictly a programming question, but questions about tools (such as SVN or VisualStudio) get asked here all the time, and I see no-one complaining there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got it now. The plugin I linked in the question works, but one has to import by creating the tiddler manually and then copy/paste the script, otherwise what comes in is messed up. Then, one has to import the ASCIIMathML.js in the header-section of the wiki-file.

Answer (score 1):

[ASciencePad](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/asciencepad/asciencepad.html) sounds like exactly what you need: TiddlyWiki + WISYWIG + AsciiMathML + AsciiSVG.

I'm not sure how to translate your existing wiki to it, but I guess you could cut-and-paste the wiki source?

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to migrate all the tiddlers from one TiddlyWiki variant to another easily. At the worst you could just copy the block of tiddlers at the bottom of the html file in a text editor and paste them into the new file. (Since the "wiki source" is that html file, I'm not saying anything different than Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin did.)

Roger_S